# Identify same lists in list (as variable) in a data.table

Tags: r, list, data.table, unique

I arranged my data in a `data.table` and created the column `livar` that contains a list or sometimes a list with lists. Each row represents multiple records for a unique record. The column `livar` aggregates all observations of a variable (not in the `data.table` anymore) of a unique record in a list or when there are multiple entries for a record then in a list of lists.

I want to check now if all the lists of one row in the column `livar` are the same. In the code provided I expected the first row in the `same` column to be `FALSE` and the second and third to be `TRUE`. As the following lines show the code works as I expected but not in the `data.table` context. Can anybody help here?

```
a <- c(123456, NA, 456789, NA, NA)
b <- c(NA, NA)
c <- c(123456, NA, 987654, NA, NA)
d <- c(123456, NA, 987654, NA, NA)
e <- c(NA, NA)

li1 <- list(a, b)
li2 <- list(c, d)

DT <- data.table(c(1,2,3))
DT[, livar := list(li1, li2, e)]
DT[, same := length(unique(livar))==1] # FALSE

length(unique(li1))==1 # FALSE
length(unique(li2))==1 # TRUE
length(unique(e))==1 # TRUE
length(unique(c(NA, NA)))==1 # TRUE
```

Comment: just missing a `*apply`: `DT[, same := sapply(livar, function(x) length(unique(x))==1L)]`

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thanks a lot. I missed this code line `DT <- data.table(c(1,2,3))` but you solved it anyway. I added the line in my question and will accept your comment as answer, when you post it. could you maybe explain a bit why you have to use sapply in the `data.table` environment?

Comment: your livar column is a list. you can going into each list of the list, for each of this list (i.e. a `sapply`), you can checking if there is only 1 unique vector

Comment: Terrific, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `chinsoon12` pointed out a *apply was missing in the following line in order to get into each list of the list.

```
DT[, same := sapply(livar, function(x) length(unique(x))==1L)]
```